# Tabs and action in the same row in the app bar

Tags: flutter

[image]

I'm trying to implement tabViews  and actions in the same row in an app bar as seen in the screen grab. The app is for an iPad so I have extra real estate to play with. The `AppBar` class has a `bottom` attribute where I've seen tabViews implemented. The action property is higher up in the app bar. Do  tabviews have to be implemented in the app bar? Ultimately how would I go about implementing the design shown. (Past 24 hrs part not necessary to implement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
DefaultTabController(
    length: 3,
    initialIndex: 0,
    child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(child: Text('ScreenOne')),
                  Tab(child: Text('ScreenTwo')),
                  Tab(child: Text('ScreenThree'))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(MaterialIcons.share),
                  onPressed: (){},
                ),
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(MaterialIcons.info),
                  onPressed: (){},
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          ScreenOne(),
          ScreenTwo(),
          ScreenThree(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```